# Unable to access Alluxio File System API in IDE

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, alluxio

I am trying to access a file in alluxio in a scala code in the IDE and i am getting this error `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: alluxio`
 
My code is as follows,

```
package com.example.sparkalliuxiodemo

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object TestMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config("spark.master", "local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    var df = spark.read.parquet("alluxio://localhost:19998/sample-df")
    df.printSchema()

  }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-alluxio-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alluxio</groupId>
            <artifactId>alluxio-core-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alluxio</groupId>
            <artifactId>alluxio-core-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alluxio</groupId>
            <artifactId>alluxio-core-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alluxio</groupId>
            <artifactId>alluxio-core-client-fs</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am able to access the alluxio file system in the Spark Installed directory via Shell. If I try to access the same via IDE, including the above alluxio dependencies in the POM.xml I am getting the above error.

If I place this jar `alluxio-1.8.1-client.jar' manually into my build path I am able to access the file in alluxio with out any error in IDE itself.

I need to access the file in alluxio directly in eclipse or scala-ide.

Can any one suggest me the right alluxio dependencies to include in the maven dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.alluxio</groupId>
        <artifactId>alluxio-core-client-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```